# Managed Navigation Sharepoint 2013 Not Show Main List with "/" url

Tags: managed-navigation

If i navigate to "http://example/Pages/Default.aspx" the navigation bar works perfectly
Nav 1:
Nav 2:
    Sub Nav 2:1
    Sub Nav 2:2
Nav 3:

but if i navigate to "http://example/" url it only shows part of the nav
Sub Nav 2:1
Sub Nav 2:2

Comment: is "eh" means default home page? If yes, the default home page is "/Pages/Default.aspx"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok removed the offending Term Set and Added it back and all is working now.